# Toggle ionic side menu via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

i just started developing mobile application with ionic and angular js. Now i added a side menu into my application.

I would like to toggle this one via javascript because i'm using angular and ionic with jquery-mobile for my page transitions etc. I would like to have a smooth transition after the page changed. `menu-close` as an attribute doesn't help me because i have to add the menu twice or more because of the single sites.

I didn't found any examples for a single page application, based on angular/ionic and jquery mobile. I only would like to use the great side menu from ionic (or is it angular)? Is it possible to use this without angular? If yes, how?

```
function toggleIt(){
    close.sideMenu;
}
```

something like that should trigger the function that looks like you've clicked on the toggle btn.

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: If you post your code I may be able to help more, but if you are making a ionic app why are you using jquery mobile, ionic is a UI framework that comes with tons of its own angular directives built in. You could use only angular and JQM and cut out ionic but using JQM with any other framework or library will come with its woes since JQM wants to try to overtake routing.

Answer (score 1):

Ionic side menus do support opening/closing them via an API call. Look at the menu-toggle directive (http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/menuToggle/) as an example. Here is a sample:

```
<button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
```

I forgot to add, you can also do $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft(); (and I assume toggleRight) to open/close side menus.